# Missing Driver for Egictec EH575 Fingerprint Reader

Tags: drivers

I've got an Egistec EH575 fingerprint reader in my Acer Swift SF314-42m running 23.10 Mantic Minotaur.

The fingerprint reader doesn't show up as an option for user login, and doesn't seem to be recognised by the system. It appears that there's no driver installed for it.

Does anyone know if there's a driver in the pipeline for future Ubuntu releases?

Comment: This is better a question for libfprint, the people who create the fingerprint driver in use by Ubuntu.  That's an open source project and they list what fingerprint readers they support.  If they already support it, then there is no timeline for 'updates' to libfprint in Ubuntu and we don't have any insights into that as Ask Ubuntu is not the Ubuntu Developers Team